# C GStreamer empty pipeline

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I am building my pipeline like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=" + video_filename + " ! qtdemux ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 ! vpudec frame-drop=0 ! queue ! imxv4l2sink device=/dev/video16
```

This is how I stop video playback

```
    gst_element_set_state (m_gst_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_main_loop_quit (m_mainloop);
    gst_object_unref(m_gst_pipeline);
```

The stopping itsself works fine, only issue is that I get the last video frame displayed even when exiting the program. How do I flush the pipeline before destruction so I have a black screen?